How to read `File` content in Javascript
My web application takes local XML files as input and it stores them in a useState variable. I would like to parse the input xml data but I'm currently unable to do so. Here's how the xml files are acquired:
const [xml, setXML] = useState(null)

function handleUpload(event) {
        setXML(event.target.files[0])
        console.log(xml)
    }

return (
    ...
    <input type='file' accept="text/xml" onChange={handleUpload} />
    ...
);

Here's what the console.log returns:
File { name: "filename.xml", lastModified: 1717088034013, webkitRelativePath: "", size: 44452, type: "text/xml" }

If I expand it I can't see the actual xml data and this is why I'm thinking that this is not the correct way of acquiring a local xml file. I've seen may suggesting the use of fetch but it sounds strange to me that that would be needed to acquire a local xml file
I went and tried parsing the xml variable anyway with the xml2js library. I followed this answer to write the following code. The console.log returns undefined
const [xml, setXML] = useState(null)

    const [xmlData, setXMLData] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
        parseString(xml, function (err, result) {
            setXMLData(result);
            console.log(result)
        });
    }, [xml])


I take it that you want the content not the File.

@ChukwujiobiCanon Yeah exactly. I would like to have a variable storing the content of the xml file. This variable should allow me to parse the xml

To read a File in Javascript, you must use a FileReader. The FileReader lets web applications asynchronously read the contents of Files (or raw data buffers) stored on the user's computer.
const reader = new FileReader()

if (xml)
{
    reader.readAsText(xml)
}
You should add an Event Listener to know when the read is done.
reader.addEventListener("load", () => console.log(reader.result))
After reading, reader.result will contain the content of the File.
If the File contains binary data, do this instead:
const reader = new FileReader()

if (binaryFile)
{
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(binaryFile)
}
Note: FileReader cannot be used to read a File by "pathname" from the user's file system. [1]

[1] This is a security feature.

Great, that works! I can then use reader.result as input for the parseString method of xml2js. I'm hoing to try and see if I can get it to work with DOMParser
